# Python Berkeley Database QUEUE

Tags: python, berkeley-db

How do you use the Berkely database queue from python? I can't find an example anywhere.

This is my best attempt so far but it raises an invalid argument error.

```
import bsddb3
import os

db = bsddb3.db.DB()
db.open(os.path.abspath("test.db"),bsddb3.db.DB_QUEUE,bsddb3.db.DB_TRUNCATE | bsddb3.db.DB_CREATE)
# Next line raises bsddb3.db.DBInvalidArgError: (22, "Invalid argument -- BDB0104 9 larger than database's maximum record length 0")
db.put(db.stat()['cur_recno'],'{"rec":1}')
print(db.consume())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call set_re_len on  a QUEUE to specify the data length. I found the solution in the documentation under record length.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17276_01/html/programmer_reference/rq_conf.html#am_conf_recno

```
import bsddb3
import os

db = bsddb3.db.DB()
db.set_re_len(1024)
db.open(os.path.abspath("test.db"),bsddb3.db.DB_QUEUE,bsddb3.db.DB_TRUNCATE | bsddb3.db.DB_CREATE)

db.put(1,'{"rec":1}'.encode('utf-8'),None,bsddb3.db.DB_APPEND)
db.put(1,'{"rec":2}'.encode('utf-8'),None,bsddb3.db.DB_APPEND)

print(db.consume()[1].decode('utf-8').strip())
print(db.consume()[1].decode('utf-8').strip())

db.close()
```

This code works but the records are fixxed length which is why this code strips the whitespace.